# Simple probability question - how to approach systematically, not overthink, or misinterpret?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, descriptive-statistics

I have been studying some probability 'story problems' and surprisingly the ones with very simple solutions tend to confuse me. Particularly, the question below.

> **The question:** Losses covered by an insurance policy are modeled by a uniform distribution on the interval [0,1000]. An
>   insurance company reimburses losses in excess of a deductible of 250.
>
> Calculate the difference between the median and the 20th percentile of
>   the insurance company reimbursement, over all losses.
>
> (A) 225
>   (B) 250
>   (C) 300
>   (D) 375
>   (E) 500

If you are young like me and don't know what a deductible is, it means for a loss $L > 0$ the insurance company will pay you a reimbursement $R = \mathrm{max}\{ L -250, 0 \}$.

> **The solution provided:**
>   Before applying the deductible, the median is 500 and the 20th percentile is 200. After applying
>   the deductible, the median payment is 500 – 250 = 250 and the 20th percentile is max(0, 200 –
>   250) = 0. The difference is 250.

I have a strong background in math but not a good foundation in probability. The solution seems so simple, but without seeing the solution I would not have been confident that method is correct and justified. Part of this may be the wording of the questions - does the part 'over all losses' make a difference? I could not figure out what that meant. Here is how I interpreted the question as I read it for the first time:

1. Losses $L$ are a random variable with distribution $L$ ~ $U[0,1000]$. (This makes the first part of the solution make sense since median and percentile of uniform distribution are trivial.)
2. Reimbursements $R$ are a new random variable and to find the median and 20th percentile I should find how $R$ is distributed.
3. For some particular loss $\ell > 0$, the reimbursement is given by $r = \mathrm{max}\{\ell - 250, 0 \}$.
4. Then a PDF for $R$ should be $$p(r) = \cases{ .25, \hspace{5mm} \text{ if } r = 0 \\ 750^{-1}, \hspace{2mm} \text{ if } r \in (0,750]} \, $$
5. Using this, I would have found a median to be 281.25 by solving for a number $k$ such that $p(0 < r < k) = p(k < r < 750)$ which is inconsistent with the solution provided.

> **My question for you:** It seems I am overthinking or misunderstanding. The solution provided seems much simpler. Is there a concept I am missing that I can learn about that would allow me to confidently and quickly answer this question?  Am I misinterpreting the question? Am I misunderstanding the definition of something? It is very important to me to feel like I understand the definitions and justifications. I do not understand why the solution provided is justified, nor would I have solved it that way on my own - so I am unsatisfied with my understanding. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a *non-deceasing* function, and $x_p$ is the $p$-th percentile of $X$, then the $p$-th percentile of $f(X)$ is $f(x_p)$. Here $f(x)=\max(x-250, 0)$. This fact is not difficult to prove once its pointed out to you, but isn't really that obvious otherwise. It's not necessarily true when $f$ is not non-decreasing. The person who wrote the solution definitely shouldn't have just used this fact implicitly like that (of course, I may be being too generous in assuming they're even aware that their argument requires something like this result, but let's not get the pitchforks out just yet).

Comment: Your first sentence looks incomplete. I assume you missed the words “is $f(x_p)$”, unless I’ve misunderstood the result you were trying to state.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Yes, that's it. Also, note that the result may not be *technically* true, depending on how you define the $p$-th percentile - the trouble is that there isn't always a unique $y$ such that $P(Y\leq y)=p$. If you define the $p$-th percentile of $Y$ to be $\sup\{y\mid P(Y\leq y)=y\}$, I think the result is true. You'd have to think through the details carefully.

Comment: I think you meant a *non-decreasing* function. To decease means to die.

Comment: @celtschk You've never studied necromathematics?

Comment: @JackM is there any special area of stats/probability where this fact is common knowledge or applied often?

Comment: @JackM this questions kind of stems from my non-rigorous understanding of random variables - but in what sense does R = f(L) where R,L are reimbursements and losses? What is the domain of L?

Comment: @PrinceM No, I came up with this result on the fly after reading your question. The domain of $L$ is some abstract probability space, which in this case you can think of as the set of all prospective clients of the insurance company. $L$ maps people onto numbers. But however you formally think of $L$, the point of that $R=f(L)$ in the sense that although $L$ is something random, for any given random value of $L$, we obtain a corresponding value of $R$ in a non-random way, by just applying $f$.

Comment: If this problem came from a course for actual insurance actuaries, maybe this rule for calculating percentiles of reimbursements is something they just learn off by heart.

Comment: Great, good explanation. Getting a clean answer on random variables is tricky because it usually gets introduced way before a student would have measure theoretic backgrounds, so explanations are kind of hand wavy.

Comment: Does it follow that if p is a pdf for X and Y = f(X) then f(p) is a pdf for Y?

Comment: @PrinceM No, definitely not! Notice that even from a "units" point of view, this doesn't make sense. $f$ is something defined on the range of $X$, so it accepts an input in "$x$-units" (in our case dollars). If $p$ is a PDF, then it's in units of *probability per $x$-unit*, so it doesn't make sense to plug it into $f$, and notice that in what I said in the answer, I in fact only ever put $x$-unit values into $f$. Of course strictly formally we don't have units in mathematics, but this is a good way of thinking about why your proposition can't be true.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Unit mismatch is a good trouble shooting method. It just seems to me that if a random variable is a transformation of another random variable, we should have some obvious formula for the pdf of the new RV

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is good but your probability density function needs to be normalized so that the total probability is 1 instead of 1.25

$$ p(r) = \cases{ .25, \hspace{5mm} \text{ if } r = 0 \\ .001, \hspace{2mm} \text{ if } r \in (0,750]} \, $$

So that the cumulative distribution is ...

$$ CDF(r) = 0.25+0.001r $$

Comment: Oh whoops. Good catch. Still, they seem to jump past all discussion of random variables and distributions in the answer provided, are their known properties I can become familiar with that would allow me to simply compute the median as old median - 250... etc?